# TAC execution plan configuration to start from the job which makes error

Tags: talend

i had a problem to configure execution plan in Talend Administrator Center. my execution plan is this : Job 0 ---On OK--->Job 1--On OK-->Job 2. For example if i run it and made error in Job 1 and i want to run it again it starts from the beginning. Could you please tell me how could i make it work from the Job that has problem and not from the beginning. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

May this will help but i didnt try it:

```
¤ Job 0
    > OnOk Job 1
        > OnError Job 1
        > OnOk Job 2
             > OnOk Job 3
```

Even if it work, i dont recommand it because you may enter an infinite loop if Job 1 still exit on error, I prefer using a master job which launch the Job 1 and control how many time it can exit on error:

Master job:

```
tLoop--------(iterate)------tRunJob[job1]--------(onSubJobOk)---------tJava
```

- tLoop: `for int i =0 ; (i < context.max_try)&& context.Again; i ++;`
- tJava: `context.Again= false;`

Comment: Actually what i want is that when i run again my execution plan :
Job 0
    > OnOk Job 1
        > OnError Kill (and when the problem is solved, it will run from Job1 without rerunning from JOb0)
        > OnOk Job 2
Is it possible to make this scenario  in TAC ?

Comment: @ily you can stop plan if job1 exit with error by using onOK, but there is no way to continue where previous execution stopped, we usually develop some jobs which uses metaservlet of talend to resolve similar problem.